# How to split array in two arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have one array and want split it in to two:

**Now:**     `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

**New_1:** `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`

**New_2:** `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

So take the one element and skip the next element.
Look easy but how can i do it with C#?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can use linq, [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and get the array with elements that have *even* and *odd* indexes.

```
var New_1 = arr.Where((c,i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray();
var New_2 = arr.Where((c,i) => i % 2 != 0).ToArray();
```

You can get the index of element of collection and apply condition to check if index is even or odd and get the arrays according.

> Enumerable.Where Method (IEnumerable, Func) filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.
>   Each element's index is used in the logic of the predicate function.
>   The first argument of predicate represents the element to test. The
>   second argument represents the zero-based index of the element within
>   source, [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Don't forget `.ToArray()`

Comment: But he wants an array as the result.  `Where()` returns an `IEnumerable`

Comment: Thanks @elmugrat, so nice of you.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
int[] arr = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int[] arr1 = arr.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray();
int[] arr2 = arr.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int i = 0;
List<int[]> twoArr = arr.GroupBy(x => i++ % 2).Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Comment: This would work, but it doesn't give OP the result he wants (two arrays) and is (IMO) less readable than the `Where()` version

Comment: @elmugrat If he wanted to split to 10, would you create 10 arrays manually. No I won't post a *bad* answer.

Comment: If he hadn't said "split it in to two", I'd agree with you, but since he only wants two, I think the improved readability is worth the extra line.