# How to split an array to 2 arrays with odd and even indices respectively?

Tags: c#, collections

How to split an array to 2 arrays with odd and even indices respectively? For example

```
int[] a = new int[]{1, 3, 7, 8};
```

then get two arrays

> a1: {1, 7} 
>   a2: {3, 8}

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847026/how-to-split-array-in-two-arrays

Answer (score 11):

Simple using the overload of [Where](http://Where%3CTSource%3E(IEnumerable%3CTSource%3E,%E2%80%82Func%3CTSource,%E2%80%82Int32,%E2%80%82Boolean%3E)) than contains the index which:

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate. Each element's
>   index is used in the logic of the predicate function.

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 3, 7, 8 };

int[] aEven = a.Where((x, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray();
int[] aOdd = a.Where((x, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: [Here is a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TJDwJ5).